# File.Exists returns False in Active Directory environment

Tags: authentication, iis, active-directory

I've got an Application under my Default Web Site in IIS 7 and whenever I try to access another document on the same domain (but different machines), `File.Exists` returns `False`, even though the document does exist and I can access it just fine from the machine hosting the site. The AD portion of the setup appears to be working fine, I'm just not able to access documents on different machines in the domain. Here's my IIS setup:

1. Application Pool: .NET 4.0, Integrated Pipeline, and using the ApplicationPoolIdentity Identity. I've tried using NetworkService but that didn't seem to make a difference.
2. Authentication: My Application has only ASP.NET Impersonation and Windows Authentication enabled. The bin folder is the same.

If there's anything else relevant to IIS set up, please let me know and I'll get it added.

I've also tried granting my machine full permissions on the folder that has the document (which is on another machine in the same domain) which I'm trying to access. That didn't seem to make a difference either.

Has anyone come across this before or know of anything else I can try or know of any IIS settings I can check? If there's anything else relevant that I can include in my setup, please let me know!

**UPDATE:**

Is it possible to find out what identity is being used or who is being impersonated when `System.IO.File.Exists()` is called, or more specifically find out who *that method* impersonates as? I've tried checking `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` right before calling `File.Exists()` and it **correctly** returns my domain user.

So it appears that isn't the user being impersonated when `File.Exists()` executes. What's more is that if, in IIS, I change the ASP.NET Impersonation (in Authentication settings) to use my specific domain user, everything works fine! But when I change it back to use the "Authenticated User", it doesn't?

I can also confirm that calling `Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name()` right before `File.Exists()` also returns the correct domain user.

**UPDATE 2:**

I've also tried setting the Application Pool Identity to my specific domain user, which doesn't seem to make a difference either. At this point, I'm not sure what other account it could be impersonating as when checking if the file exists?

**UPDATE 3:**

I've tried using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) on the machine which has the documents I'm trying to access, but when I filter it down to the file type I'm looking for (or expecting to see), nothing shows up when I re-run my tests. I can only assume doing a `File.Exists()` on a file you don't have access to, doesn't register to the Process Monitor? Are there any other ways for me to find out which impersonated user/service is trying (unable) to access these documents?

**UPDATE 4:**

Using the examples found by @john below, I've tried to programmatically impersonate the logged in user before checking if the file exists:

```
Dim wID As WindowsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
Dim ctx As WindowsImpersonationContext = Nothing

ctx = wID.Impersonate()

If System.IO.File.Exists(sFile) Then

Else
   'Still gets here?
End If
```

However, `File.Exists()` still returns false even when impersonating.

**UPDATE 5 (SOLUTION):**

I needed this:

```
Using ctx As System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero)
   'My code here
End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS, select your website, then goto Authentication, select Windows Authentication,

1. Select Advanced Settings -> make sure kernel mode is enabled
2. Select Provider, check if Negotiate is the first item in the mapping

When you test only use IE and running from your Intranet.

Also you can impersonate a specific user, goto ASP.NET impersonation, specify the user who has access to the remote directory.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I double checked and I've got those settings set correctly already. Also, testing in IE made no difference (I was using Chrome before).

Comment: Actually, your last point kind of worked - when I changed the ASP.NET Impersonation from "Authenticated User" to my account specifically, it works fine. What I don't get though, is why it wasn't using my account when it was set to "Authenticated User"? What's more, when "Authenticated User" is used, I've even tried calling `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` before checking if the file exists, and made sure it returns the correct "domain\username", and it does!

Comment: It has to do with the Web server being unable to pass the credential to your remote machine with Kerberos, see http://forums.iis.net/t/1114220.aspx/1 for explanation. There is another way I have used that programmatically impersonates when you need to check the file, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx

Comment: Thanks again. Reading through the "double hop" scenario, that sounds like it could be the problem. However, I tried to programmatically impersonate using the `WindowsImpersonationContext` example, and after calling `Impersonate()`, `File.Exists()` still returns false (I'll update my post to show you the code I used) AHH!

Comment: Interesting, I just ran a test, works fine for me, but I had to use IE, otherwise it doesn't work. Also I'm assuming you are using Classic for the app pool and <identity impersonate="false" />

Comment: Actually, I'm using Integrated for the app pool, and I'm not specifying impersonate=false in the Web.config (not using the `<Impersonate>` tag at all). I think I would want to use impersonation, correct? I have ASP.NET Impersonation enabled for the site in IIS under Authentication.

Comment: After further testing, if I wrap my entire function (not just `File.Exists()`) with `using (var ctx = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero))` it seems to do the trick!